# Will Microsoft Money work on Vista or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, microsoft-money

I have been using Microsoft Money 2000 (UK version) for many years, and don’t wish to witch to another product if possible.   However our main computers run Vista and Windows 7 now, our XP machine are on their last legs!

So it is possible run Microsoft Money on Vista or Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just installed Ms Money 2000 Standard (UK) from a Works Suite 2000 CD set and it seems to install OK on vista.   It can access the “my money.mvy” file I copied from my old machine.

However it can’t download any Component Updates, I get the error “Component Update: The operation failed” when I update my stock price.

If I “right click” on MS Money as choose “Run as Admin” the “Component Update: The operation failed” error goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is: [Running Microsoft Money on Windows 7](http://money.mvps.org/faq/article/626.aspx)

Comment: this seems to be Ms-Money 2005

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact reason Microsoft introduced [XP Mode in Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Windows_XP_Mode):

> Windows 7's new XP Mode lets you
>   seamlessly run virtualized
>   applications alongside your regular
>   Windows 7 applications—so your
>   outdated software will continue to
>   work.

If installing/running MS Money 2000 normally doesn't work, try [installing it as a virtual XP application](http://lifehacker.com/5245396/set-up-and-use-xp-mode-in-windows-7). Note there are minimal hardware/OS requirements, but most recent computers should be fine.

XP Mode basically emulates a windows XP machine inside your Windows 7, so XP Mode applications should not be able to tell the difference between running in a real XP installation and an XP Mode one. More background info on XP Mode:

- [Windows 7's XP Mode: what it is, how it works, who it's for](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/reviews/2010/01/windows-xp-mode.ars)
- [Windows Virtual PC and Windows XP Mode](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/ff_xpmode.asp)
- [Download Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)

Comment: To quote "Windows XP mode was not released for, and will fail to function on, any editions of Windows 7 below Professional Edition." given that MS-Money is a home product Windows XP mode is not a option for most people

Comment: @Ian, it's also possible to use another VM to do the same thing. VirtualBox has a headless mode that is essentially the same thing as XP Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Money 2003 on my Win 7 Pro machine with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I installed UK Money 2000 on my new Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit PC, and it worked, but wouldn't download any quotes. After a bit of searching I recalled the quote server changed a couple of years ago and needs a registry edit. Having done this, it works fine again. I have not had to run it in any compatibility modes.

You need this advice:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8dc8c86-a250-4344-9f78-faa8a0b078ec/online-quotes

and may also need the UKpence2k.zip bug fix for UK users, see here:
http://money.mvps.org/faq/article/47.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have recently replaced my old XP machine with a new desktop PC running Windows 7 64 bit.  I have been able to install MS Money 2000 (version 8) UK edition from my Works Suite 2000 CD, and so far I haven't experienced any problems.  I have seen [reports](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Microsoft%20money%202000&v=Microsoft&uid=8&l=en&pf=1&pi=5&s=Microsoft%20Money&os=64-bit) that this version of Money is not compatible with Windows 7, but am not clear whether these are installation issues, or whether some functions don't work properly.

It is good to see that there is a download available from Microsoft of [QFE for UK version of Money 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26915). As I understand it, this gives us the last version of the UK version of Money, and may provide an upgrade path if I find I can't run Money 2000 at some stage in the future.  However, I wont be leaving Money 2000 until I have to - in my view it is more usable than later versions, and does everything I need it to.